# how to bind several columns to one variable in PDO like query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I have a variable `$search` and I want to search for records containing the `$search` in multiple columns

```
$query="Select * from products where name LIKE ? OR color LIKE ?"
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
$results=$stmt->execute(array("%$search%","%$search%"));
```

but when I try to execute `print_r($results);`, I get nothing displayed  except for a '1'.The problem perhaps is binding of the `$search` variable to the query.So I am curious whether there's a way to handle such a situation and what's the best working alternative.Thanks

Comment: all you've done is run your query. You haven't FETCHED anything. In real-world terms, you've placed your order at the fast food counter, you've got your numbered receipt in-hand, now you actually have to GET your food.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out @MarcB ...Actually I have touched PHP after a long time ...forgot that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$results is the success status of the PDOStatement execution; the returned rows are still in the $stmnt object. You need to iterate over the returned rows and print the individually.

```
while ($row = $stmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

will work.

Comment: Damn I forgot that and assumed it to be the associative array.My fault:). Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following:

```
while ($row = $stmnt->fetch()) {

       echo $row['YOUR COLUMNS NAME HERE'].'<br>';
}
```

or use bind columns:

```
$stmt->bindColumn('COLUMN 1 NAME', $variable1);
$stmt->bindColumn('COLUMN 2 NAME', $variable2);
$stmt->bindColumn('COLUMN 3 NAME', $variable3);
//...... GO ON LIKE THIS
$stmt->execute();
```